# Trac on shared server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-wsgi, trac

I'm facing an odd problem with Trac's authentication. I have it installed in other servers and never had problem to install it, but now I'm trying to install it on a shared linux server where:

- don't have access to `httpd.conf`;
- only available scripts are php and python (wsgi);
- no dev tools at all (so no chance to use gcc to compile something);
- `.htaccess` is okay.

Well, trac is installed and working in anonymous mode and I can not find a way to make it private. It looks like it only [relies](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModWSGI#ConfiguringAuthentication) on Apache basic authentication but I can not do this without `httpd.conf` access.

On my other instalations I use `<Location>` inside `httpd.conf`, but I can't use this tag inside `.htaccess`. I know that I can simply put `<Location>`'s content inside a `.htaccess` file and put this file in any `www` subdirectory to protect it. But since this is a `wsgi` script in another directory outside `www` I have no place to put that `.htaccess`.

I'm looking for a way to solve this by:

- still using apache auth with any other `.htaccess` configuration that I've missed;
- any other way Trac could be used in privative besides relying on apache;
- any other issue/project tracking similar to trac is an option too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [AccountManagerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) on a shared Linux server machine of mine without issues.